# How to fix "an expression of type null is ineligible for implicit conversion"

Tags: scala, ensime, quill.io

When inspecting this code:

```
def getFilmById(filmId: Long) = quote {
  query[Film].filter(f => f.film_id == lift(filmId))
}
```

ensime shows an error in place of opening brace:

> an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion

The application compiles and query is generated properly, only editor marks it as a compile error.

I'm using quill 3.1.0, ensime 2.5.1, emacs 26.2-1 scala 2.12.8.

I expect no compilation error shown in editor.

Comment: Bugs should be reported at bug tracker http://ensime.github.io/editors/emacs/troubleshooting/

Comment: @DmytroMitin I didn't know if that's a bug or just something missing in my code. I'm just starting with ensime, but thank you.

Comment: You wrote "The application compiles and query is generated properly, only editor marks it as a compile error." This means it can't be something missing in your code.